# Prove/disprove that if $(n a_n)$ is bounded then $(a_n)$ converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I need to prove or disprove the following statement:

> If $(n a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$

I think the statement is true but I'm not sure about my proof:

Because $(n a_n)$ is bounded there exists $M>0$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |n a_n|<M$ or $|a_n|<\frac{M}{n}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $N=\lceil\frac{M}{\varepsilon}\rceil$ (note that $N>\frac{M}{\varepsilon}$). Then $\forall n>N$ we have $|a_n-0|=|a_n|<\frac{M}{n}<\frac{M}{N}<\varepsilon$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good.,,,,

Comment: @N.S. - thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct and well-presented. Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your proof seems right. Another way, I think we can sketch the proof (intuitively), is assume $(na_n)$ is bounded, and (assume) that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=S$ where $S$ is non-zero. Let $(na_n)$ be bounded by $R$. So $|na_n| \le R$ for all $n \ge 1$. Now, for large enough $n$, say $n=n'$: $a_n$ would be close to $S$, and $n \cdot a_n$ would thus be close to $n'S$ - which (if we choose $n'$ large enough) - as $S \neq 0$, would either be larger than $R$, or smaller than $-R$. This contradicts the assumption $|na_n| \le R$. Cheers.